# How to open terminal in dolphin?

Tags: shortcut-keys, kde, dolphin

In Ubuntu 13.04 with KDE desktop is there any way to do an action like "Open terminal" in Dolphin? Can it be done using a hotkey?

Comment: for anyone that wonder where is the `open terminal here` button in dolphin

`right click, actions there you got open terminal here`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In the dolphin file manager just press the <kbd>F4</kbd> function key and that will open a terminal inside dolphin, in the same directory.

[image: Dolphin file manager showing nested terminal window]

To open a separate terminal window, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>; or right-click in the directory contents pane and choose *Actions > Open Terminal Here*.

---

**Note:** As Dolphin is KDE-based the default terminal emulator it launches is Konsole, so if you only get an empty area instead of a terminal, try running

```
sudo apt-get install konsole
```

Comment: Do you know of any way to make it put the terminal on the side instead of the top/bottom?

Comment: Give me time. I will try and let you know.

Comment: You can also press `Shift+F4` in Dolphin to open current directory in a separate terminal window, or click through *Control* -> *Tools* -> *Open Terminal* if you want to use mouse.

Comment: This does not work for me. When I try to either enable it via the menu or F4 key, all that happens is the list window will either expand to the bottom of the main Dolphin window or contract. But, no actual terminal window will show up within the Dolphin app itself. I've seen it work before, not sure if I performed an update that broke this functionality or what... I'm running Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @user3328969 Same here with Xubuntu 18

Comment: @user3328969 Just had the same problem and fixed it through `sudo apt-get install konsole`

Comment: @Stabledog drag the terminal to the desired position, close, and the next time is in this place.

Comment: Is there a way to have it opened by default?