# How to add "New Terminal" to right click menu of desktop in Kubuntu?

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, launcher, kde

Kubuntu: 16.04.2 LTS

Question: How do you add "New Terminal" to the right click menu of desktop?

More details on the problem.

Common strategy that does not work: "Add Favorites Launcher to Mouse Actions".
However, with the latest Kubuntu, "Favorites Launcher" is not an option.

See image below.

[image: kubuntu screenshot]

So I tried installing the Favorites Launcher add-on via this website:
https://addons.videolan.org/p/1081011

However, the above add-on has compiler errors, and the add-on does not exist when searching in the Kubuntu software center (called Discover in Kubuntu).

What other things can I try?

Comment: according to another question (https://askubuntu.com/questions/336920/how-to-open-terminal-in-dolphin#336921) you may do `Shift+F4` for a new terminal window, and `F4` for just an embedded one.

Comment: Is it for desktop or any folder in dolphin? Because within dolphin, it's already there!!

Comment: Anwar, this is for desktop. I went to edit the post to clarify and see that you did that for me! Thank you :).

Answer (score 1):

**KDE Mouse/Containment action plugins**

( copy of https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=83&t=132075#p354748 )

**Plasma 4**

Tutorial
 - KDE Techbase - Plasma4 ContainmentAction: https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Plasma4/ContainmentAction

KDE Store

- Favorites Launcher: https://store.kde.org/p/1081011/
- KDE desktop
  custom menu:
  https://store.kde.org/content/show.php/+kde-desktop-custom-menu?action=content&content=170062

**Plasma 5**

KDE Store
- Plasma custom desktop menu: https://store.kde.org/p/998904/
--> source: https://github.com/MatMoul/plasma-containmentactions-customdesktopmenu

**With the Kubuntu & Plasma 5**

Downloading the plasma-containmentactions-customdesktopmenu-master.zip from https://github.com/MatMoul/plasma-containmentactions-customdesktopmenu
[image]

Installing build dependencies:

- build-essential
- cmake
- extra-cmake-modules
- qtbase5-dev
- plasma-framework-dev
- kio-dev

Generic commands:

```
mkdir -p builddir
cd builddir && cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(kf5-config --prefix) -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DKDE_INSTALL_USE_QT_SYS_PATHS=ON
make
sudo make install
```

**Build example:**

Unpacking the plasma-containmentactions-customdesktopmenu-master.zip

At /Downloads/plasma-containmentactions-customdesktopmenu-master/src

```
$ mkdir -p builddir

$ cd builddir && cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(kf5-config --prefix) -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DKDE_INSTALL_USE_QT_SYS_PATHS=ON
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found KF5Plasma: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/KF5Plasma/KF5PlasmaConfig.cmake (found version "5.33.0") 
-- Found KF5KIO: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/KF5KIO/KF5KIOConfig.cmake (found version "5.33.0") 
-- Found KF5: success (found version "5.33.0") found components:  Plasma KIO 
-- Looking for __GLIBC__
-- Looking for __GLIBC__ - found
-- Performing Test _OFFT_IS_64BIT
-- Performing Test _OFFT_IS_64BIT - Success
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/tryme/Downloads/plasma-containmentactions-customdesktopmenu-master/src/builddir

$ make
Scanning dependencies of target plasma_containmentactions_customdesktopmenu_automoc
[ 20%] Generating plasma-containmentactions-customdesktopmenu.json
About to parse service type file "plasma-containmentactions.desktop"
Found property definition "X-Plasma-HasConfigurationInterface" with type "bool"
Generated  "/home/tryme/Downloads/plasma-containmentactions-customdesktopmenu-master/src/builddir/plasma-containmentactions-customdesktopmenu.json" 

[ 40%] Automatic moc for target plasma_containmentactions_customdesktopmenu
Generating customdesktopmenu.moc
Generating moc_customdesktopmenu.cpp
[ 40%] Built target plasma_containmentactions_customdesktopmenu_automoc
Scanning dependencies of target plasma_containmentactions_customdesktopmenu
[ 60%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/plasma_containmentactions_customdesktopmenu.dir/customdesktopmenu.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/plasma_containmentactions_customdesktopmenu.dir/plasma_containmentactions_customdesktopmenu_automoc.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX shared module plasma_containmentactions_customdesktopmenu.so
[100%] Built target plasma_containmentactions_customdesktopmenu

$ sudo make install
[sudo] password for tryme: 
[ 20%] Automatic moc for target plasma_containmentactions_customdesktopmenu
[ 40%] Built target plasma_containmentactions_customdesktopmenu_automoc
[100%] Built target plasma_containmentactions_customdesktopmenu
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Installing: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma_containmentactions_customdesktopmenu.so
-- Installing: /usr/share/kservices5/plasma-containmentactions-customdesktopmenu.desktop
```

At here:[image]

Answer (score 1):

*Below was originally part of the Question and has now been moved into a CW*

Special thanks to user26687 for providing a working solution. The common strategy of using the "favorites launcher" does not with the latest Kubuntu (see below for details). Here's a summary of the steps taken to resolve this issue plus some additional things I learned that may help others:

1. Install dependencies:

```
    sudo apt-get install build-essential
    sudo apt-get install cmake
    sudo apt-get install extra-cmake-modules
    sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev
    sudo apt-get install plasma-framework-dev
    sudo apt-get install kio-dev
```

2. Download the zip files here

   https://github.com/MatMoul/plasma-containmentactions-customdesktopmenu

The default install location is in `~/Downloads`, so chances are you'll want to run the following commands:

```
    cd ~/Downloads
    unzip plasma-containmentactions-customdesktopmenu-master.zip
    cd plasma-containmentactions-customdesktopmenu-master/src
```

3. Install "Custom Desktop Menu"

```
    mkdir -p builddir
    cd builddir && cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(kf5-config --prefix) -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DKDE_INSTALL_USE_QT_SYS_PATHS=ON
    make
    sudo make install
```

4. There will now be a "Custom Desktop Menu". The "Desktop Settings" can be oppened in one of three ways: Right click the desktop and click "Configure Desktop", or clicking anywhere on the desktop and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, or clicking the small lines on the top left and clicking "Desktop Settings". Note that the first option will be gone once you're using the custom menu.
5. Once in the Desktop Settings, click "Mouse Actions" on the left, and click the drop-down for the "Right-Button" and select "Custom Desktop Menu". Note that there's a Configure button just to the right of it that will bring up some text you can modify to your hearts desire for the custom menu. It wasn't too hard to figure out the Configuration part, but if you want help with it let me know.

6) Other things learned: I had no idea about "KDE Plasma", but you can figure out what Plasma version you're using by clicking the menu button on the bottom left, typing "kinfocenter" and hitting enter. A nice GUI will come up with all the info you need.